# List of rogue antivirus/ Antimalware Software

Tags: anti-virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free antivirus solutions for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows)

What are the different rogue antivirus software that is currently available for download in the internet today

Comment: what do you mean by *"rogue antivirus software"*?  this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_security_software

Comment: Probably this is the most updated list

Comment: another list http://www.spywarewarrior.com/rogue_anti-spyware.htm
(how can a black list could be a duplicate of a white list?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another list of rogue software (1 year old though)

http://www.freepcsecurity.co.uk/2009/01/16/list-of-known-malicious-sites-rogue-software/

Another list with few of them:

http://www.tech-linkblog.com/list-of-rogue-antivirus-sites-august-4-2009